# How to make the syntax of this dictionary work in Python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am trying to output

"MDA ..." the ... will contain what the last_mda does. However, I know this is an invalid syntax. So how can I make it work?

```
reset_records={"MDA " last_mda :reboot_secs}
```

Comment: When you say output, are you trying to print it?  Or just assign it to that variable?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to print the value reset_records that is assigned "MDA" last_mda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create an empty dictionary and put values to it like in following example:

```
reset_records = {}
for name in ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']:
    reset_records['MDA'+name] = name
```

then for specific `last_mda` and `reboot_secs` it would be:

```
reset_records = {}
reset_records['MDA '+last_mda] = reboot_secs
```

please notice that `last_mda` **must be *string* type** to make it possible to add it to string - if `last_mda` is not string just use `str(last_mda)`